# custom ban reason with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that works with only one command, the bot sends a message with two buttons, one for muting and one for banning, after selecting an option the bot updates the message with other buttons for the reasons, some of them are premade and one button is for custom reasons, after one is selected, will appear a confirmation or cancellation button
i dont undestand how to make the bot to listen to a message that the user sends after the custom reason button is clicked

i tried something with filters and collectors but i don't understand how to arrange them correctly

Comment: Can you provide your current code ?